# read lines from text file and use them to rename files

Tags: batch-file, line, file-rename

How can I do the following in a batch file?

I have, for example, two files named `red.txt` and `orange.txt`

in the same directory folder I have a textfile `kite.txt` with contents being two filenames:

```
red.txt
orange.txt
```

How can I read the contents of `kite.txt` line by line from the command line and rename the actual files in my folder to be?

```
redkite.txt
orangekite.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%a in (kite.txt) do ren "%%a" "%%~nakite%%~xa"
```

Answer (score 0):

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %g in (kite.txt) do ren %g %h

**OR**

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%g in (kite.txt) do ren %%g %%h

Use single % in command line, or double % in script file

**for /f**    *For each row of kite.txt the do statement is performed*

**Tokens= 1,2**    *Names columns to be read into your variables %g, %h, etc*

**delims=,**       *Defines comma as delimiter (for CSV)*

**first %g**       *Arbitrary starting point for auto-increment variables, case sensitive, must be single letter*

**do ren**         *Runs DOS command REN with content of column1 (%g) and column2(%h) as parameters*

use **do echo %g %h** to see value of variables first if desired.